# Existence of a prime in $(\phi(n), n]$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, totient-function, prime-gaps

The question is: for any $n\geq2$, is there always a prime $p$ satifying $\varphi(n)<p\leq n$?

Here $\varphi(n)$ is the Euler totient function.

We know that there is always a prime between $n-O(n^\theta)$ and $n$, where $\theta$ can be $0.525$ ([Wiki: Prime gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds)). Under Riemann hypothesis, one can improve this bound to $O(\sqrt n\log^2n)$. But on the other hand, there are infinite many $n$ such that $\phi(n)\geq n-C\sqrt n$ for some constant $C$ (just choose $n=p(p+k)$ where $p$ and $p+k$ are both prime; for some $k$ these $p$ are infinite). So these upper bound for prime gap don't help.

So can we prove this propsition, or give a counterexample? (or give a evidence to explan why is this hard to prove, maybe?)

(The propsition is equivalent to: if $\varphi(n)>\varphi(k)$ for all $1\leq k<n$, then $n$ is prime)

Comment: By a simple program running on my laptop, there is no counterexample under $10^{10}$.

Comment: Also, there is always a prime in the interval $[n-\sqrt{n},n]$ for all $5504 \leq n \leq 4 \cdot 10^{18}$. Hence there is no counterexample under $4\cdot 10^{18}$.

Answer (score 1):

For prime numbers $n$ the claim is trivial. If $n$ is composite then we have the upper bound
$$
\phi(n)<n-\sqrt{n}.
$$
If we can show that there is always a prime between $n-\sqrt{n}$ and $n$, for $n\ge 3$, then the claim follows. Unfortunately this is not yet clear, see [At least one prime between N and N-(sqrtN)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668959/at-least-one-prime-between-n-and-n-sqrtn).

Reference: [Upper bound for Euler's totient function on composite numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896920/upper-bound-for-eulers-totient-function-on-composite-numbers)

Comment: why "There is always a prime between $n−\sqrt{n}$ and $n$"?

Comment: It's so hard to improve the upper bound of prime gap, I think this is not the right way (if there is a right way)

Comment: On the other hand $\phi(n)$ can be so large for composite $n$, so it cannot be avoided, I think.

Comment: But maybe we can divide all natural numbers to several sorts and prove it in some steps. Not all $n-\varphi(n)$ is about $\sqrt n$.